# How to fill void under bathroom vanity before installing laminate flooring and legged vanity

Tags: bathroom, flooring, laminate, vanity

We are removing an old floor mounted vanity and wanting to install new laminate flooring throughout the bathroom.  We are planning to install a vanity with legs, not tight to the floor (one we can clean under).

We do not want to remove all of the old linoleum prior to installing the vinyl flooring. This leaves a void under the vanity of that depth. How do we fill the void where the old vanity was prior to installing the new laminate installation?

Answer (score 1):

A few ideas to raise that area ~1/8":

- Use a second layer of your flooring underlayment.
- Cut cereal boxes to fit and staple in place.
- Skim with a floor leveling product.
- Purchase an inexpensive roll of vinyl flooring and cut it to fit. Staple it in place.